# Is there a way to write single bands raster from multi-band layer faster in r?

Tags: raster, r, multi-band

I have 1000 multi-layer rasters and have to export each separate layer to a tif.

Some friends recommended R to do the job. I used the following code:

```
library(raster)

namesVector<- c("layer1", "layer2", etc) #contain layer names

stack <- stack("multiLayerRaster.tif") #20 layers, total 2 GB

s <- unstack(stack)

for(i in seq_along(s)){writeRaster(s[[i]], file=namesVector[i])}
```

The code works fine, but it is very slow, it takes about 20 min to export layers from one multiLayerRaster.

Is there anyway to make the process faster?

Any advice is highly welcomed!

Comment: I don't think there's any need to unstack, just use s <- stack("multiLayerRaster.tif"). Don't call your object "stack". Loop on seq_len(nlayers(s)) and you'll have to add .tif to the file name otherwise it will be "native raster" format. There are also options to tile and compress tifs.

Comment: I would recommend gdal_translate for this kind of processing, though. Or, even better, just build vrt's using gdalbuildvrt so that you don not duplicate your images.

Comment: mdsumner: thanks, I did that already, sorry that I didn't make it clear

Comment: radouxju: I will try that and see if it is faster, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there´s a faster way to do that, but what you can do is a list in a table with the name of each multilayerraster with an identifier (column names: id & name, in this order). So you can write this:

```
#load the table with the name of the image & id
list<-read.table("Table.txt",header=T)

# select "automatic" correlative id 
id<-id+1

#select the name of your image from the table
for(i in 1:length(list[,1])) {if (list[i,1]==id) {image<-list[i,2]} }
image

#set work directory
setwd(your directory)

#load image
stack<-stack(image)
```

then you can run x times your script!!!